# Extract Google Drive multi zip from Google colab notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, unzip, zip

I have a sequence of multiple zip files: `'train.zip.001'`, `'train.zip.002'`, `'train.zip.003'`, `'train.zip.004'` and `'train.zip.005'` on Google Drive. They are 8GB each. I don't know how to extract them.

I tried:

```
    with Zipfile.ZipFile('train.zip','r') as zipob:
      zipob.extractall('train2')

    with Zipfile.ZipFile('train.zip.001','r') as zipob:
      zipob.extractall('train2')
```

They gave two different errors:

---

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ebacbe394be2> in <module>()
----> 1 with zipfile.ZipFile('train.zip','r') as zipob:
      2   zipob.extractall('train2')

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1197         if not endrec:
-> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1199         if self.debug > 1:
   1200             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
!unzip train.zip.001
Archive:  train.zip.001
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of train.zip.001 or
        train.zip.001.zip, and cannot find train.zip.001.ZIP, period.
```

Both do not work.

Comment: !7z x train.zip.001 this one working

Comment: Try after renaming the file. A one liner I often use is !unzip "file.zip" -d "target-dir"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried extract 64 7z file like 7z.001, 7z.002 file,...
To solve it, I have used:

```
!7z x "/content/drive/My Drive/GitHub/DATA/images.7z.001" -tsplit
```

May be it is useful for you...